# How do I get the sound level in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

For a project I am doing I need to get the live decibel level of my mic.

I have seen the plotters:

```py
# Print out realtime audio volume as ascii bars

import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    print ("|" * int(volume_norm))

with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
    sd.sleep(10000)
```

But i just need the volume as an integer, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the number instead of bars:

```
def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    print(int(volume_norm))
```